# iBeacon AltBeacon- didEnterRegion not getting Called everytime while scanning for iBeacon using the AltBeacon Library in Android

Tags: android

The code I have used for scanning the iBeacons is:

**Bound the Beacon Service using the:**

```java
      mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);   
         mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));   
         mBeaconManager.bind(this);
```

**I have set the Monitoring and ranging at the same time using the below code:**

```java
    mBeaconRegion = new Region("myRangingUniqueId",
            Identifier.parse(UUID), null, null); mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(mBeaconRegion);
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mBeaconRegion);
```

**In onBeaconServiceConnect method**

```java
     @override
        public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {     
          Log.d("*Beacon", "on Service Connect");          
          mBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

         @override
          public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {      
             Log.d("*Beacon", "on Enter");   
          }  

          @override
          public void didExitRegion(Region region) {     
            Log.d("*Beacon", "on Exit");      
          }

          @override     
          public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {     
             Log.d("*Beacon", "on determinate state");
          }
        });   

        mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection beacons, Region region) {
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
          Log.d("*Beacon", "size > 0");
        } else {
          Log.d("*Beacon", "size < 0");
        }
      }
    });
    }
```

**Unbinded the Beacon Service using the**

```java
    if (mBeaconManager != null) {
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
        mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();        
        mBeaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(mBeaconRegion);
        mBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(mBeaconRegion)
    }
```

When I have bound the beacon service `onBeaconServiceConnect` method is called and monitoring and ranging are started.
In Monitoring the `didDetermineStateForRegion` method is called and the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` gets executed every one second.

I came to know one thing that whenever `didEnterRegion` gets called after the `didDetermineStateForRegion` then I am getting the Beacons list otherwise I am getting the Beacon size as zero.

Here are the logs that I captured:

I am scanning for **5** seconds when the user taps on the Buttons and when the beacon is not connected within 5 Seconds I am unbinding the Beacon Service.

The actions that I am performing are only when the app is in Foreground

```
**Log 1: (Did not connect to Beacon)**
2020-02-05 16:43:47.791 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Service Connect
2020-02-05 16:43:47.805 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: Ranging
2020-02-05 16:43:47.840 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state0
2020-02-05 16:43:49.104 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size < 0
2020-02-05 16:43:50.208 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size < 0
2020-02-05 16:43:51.311 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size < 0
2020-02-05 16:43:52.413 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size < 0
2020-02-05 16:43:52.964 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: unbinding
2020-02-05 16:44:23.067 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state1
2020-02-05 16:44:23.067 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Enter

**Log2: (Connected)**

2020-02-05 16:48:24.014 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Service Connect
2020-02-05 16:48:24.026 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: Ranging
2020-02-05 16:48:24.055 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state0
2020-02-05 16:48:24.644 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state1
2020-02-05 16:48:24.644 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Enter
2020-02-05 16:48:25.309 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size > 0
2020-02-05 16:48:25.313 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: unbinding

**Log3: (Connected)**

2020-02-05 16:48:38.901 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Service Connect
2020-02-05 16:48:38.913 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: Ranging
2020-02-05 16:48:38.939 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state0
2020-02-05 16:48:39.283 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state1
2020-02-05 16:48:39.283 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Enter
2020-02-05 16:48:40.177 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size > 0
2020-02-05 16:48:40.182 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: unbinding

**Log4 (Connected)**

2020-02-05 17:00:49.768 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Service Connect
2020-02-05 17:00:49.782 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: Ranging
2020-02-05 17:00:49.807 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state0
2020-02-05 17:00:51.033 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size < 0
2020-02-05 17:00:52.028 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on determinate state1   
2020-02-05 17:00:52.028 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: on Enter
2020-02-05 17:00:52.136 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: size > 0
2020-02-05 17:00:52.139 19341-19341/com.app.example D/*Beacon: unbinding
```

can you please explain why the `didEnterRegion` is not getting called every time after the `didDetermineStateForRegion` and why I am unable to get the Beacons list in `onBeaconServiceConnect` method? Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think it is realistic to expect that beacons always be detected in 5 seconds.  If you have a beacon nearby that advertises at 10Hz, there is a high chance of this working on some Android devices.  But on other Android devices that are slower to scan, you will often not succeed in detecting BLE beacon devices that don't advertise very frequently.  I suggest you simply extend the time you scan to longer than 5 seconds.

Comment: When I use the other Beacons apps like BeaconScope or Locate I am getting the Beacons list in the other apps in that 5 secs. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: I came to know one thing that whenever didEnterRegion gets called after the didDetermineStateForRegion then I am getting the Beacons list otherwise I am getting the Beacon size as zero. Can I know why this is happening?

Comment: didEnterRegion is called only if beacons are detected.  Same goes for didRangeBeconsInRegion with a non-empty list.  The simple explanation is you are not detecting beacons.  Apps like Locate and BeaconScope start up ranging/monitoring and leave it on.  I suspect the device you are using simply takes a bit longer to start scanning, so 5 seconds may not be enough.